# Changing console.writeline redirect

Tags: c#, listbox, console.writeline

I would like to modify the Console.WriteLine redirect method. Below is the redirect code I was using (works perfectly) but between //modified comments is added code that does not do what I need.
I'd like the string in Console.writeline(string) to also be copied to another listbox but the listbox changes. FE, right now I was doing it like this: I write Console.WriteLine("sometext"+"**i"); where i shows to what listbox the string should also be written.
The current code is not working. Nothing appears in the other listbox where it should be copied and lines are written double in the default listbox.
In the previous version, I didn't use the 'override WriteLine' and '½' mark. Instead I checked for '\0' to show the end of string (this is commented out in the code below). This didn't give the bad double line in the default listbox and wrote something in the other one. The problem is that with multiline strings it only added the last line to the other listbox (buth the whole one to the default one).

Is there a better way to do this?
Please help

> 

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SefelecTester
{
    public class ListBoxWriter : TextWriter//this class redirects console.writeline to debug listbox
    {
        private delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        //TextWriter _writer = null;//for TextBoxWriter
        private ListBox list;
        //modified
        private ListBox list2;
        private ListBox list3;
        private int select=0;
        //--modified

        private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        public ListBoxWriter(ListBox list, ListBox list2, ListBox list3)
        {
            this.list = list;
            //modified
            this.list2 = list2;
            this.list3 = list3;
            //--modified
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            //this.rtbIncoming.Text += text;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            content.Append(value);
            //modified
            if (value == '½')
            //if (value == '\0')//previous version
            {
                this.list.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list.Items.Add(content.ToString())));
                select = 0;
                return;//not in previous version
            }
            if (select!=1 ||select!=2)
            {
                if (select == 10)
                {
                    this.list.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list.Items.Add(content.ToString())));
                    select = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(value);
                }
                else if (value == '*' && select == 5)
                {
                    this.list.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list.Items.Add(content.ToString())));
                    select = 10;
                }
                else if (value == '*')
                {
                    this.list.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list.Items.Add(content.ToString())));
                    select = 5; 
                }

            }
            //--modified
            if (value == '\n')
            {
                // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
                // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
                // If these threads are different, it returns true.
                if (this.list.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                    //this.Invoke(d, new object[] { content.ToString() });
                    try
                    {
                        this.list.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list.Items.Add(content.ToString())));
                        this.list.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list.SelectedIndex = list.Items.Count - 1));
                        this.list.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list.SelectedIndex = -1));
                    }
                    catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exception raised(" + ex.Message + "): " + ex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Items.Add(content.ToString());
                    list.SelectedIndex = list.Items.Count - 1;
                    list.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
                //modified
                if(select>0)
                {
                    if(select==1)
                    {
                        if (this.list2.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                            //this.Invoke(d, new object[] { content.ToString() });
                            try
                            {
                                this.list2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list2.Items.Add(content.ToString())));
                                this.list2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list2.SelectedIndex = list2.Items.Count - 1));
                                this.list2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list2.SelectedIndex = -1));
                            }
                            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Exception raised(" + ex.Message + "): " + ex);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list2.Items.Add(content.ToString());
                            list2.SelectedIndex = list2.Items.Count - 1;
                            list2.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(select==2)
                    {
                        if (this.list.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                            //this.Invoke(d, new object[] { content.ToString() });
                            try
                            {
                                this.list3.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list3.Items.Add(content.ToString())));
                                this.list3.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list3.SelectedIndex = list3.Items.Count - 1));
                                this.list3.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => list3.SelectedIndex = -1));
                            }
                            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Exception raised(" + ex.Message + "): " + ex);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list3.Items.Add(content.ToString());
                            list3.SelectedIndex = list3.Items.Count - 1;
                            list3.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //--modified
                //list.Items.Add(content.ToString());
                content = new StringBuilder();

            }
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }

        //modified
        public override void WriteLine(string text)
        {
            base.WriteLine(text+"½");
            return;
        }
        //--modified
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering - why is it not feasible to wrap the WriteLine AND your additional functionality up into a 3rd method and call that?

Comment: I tried that but this has other problems. Maybe someone can help with these instead. Several form need to use that wrapper but if I make it static then I can't give it instance of main form. I need that instance to call invoke on the other listboxes. OR is there a way to use invoke otherwise to make the call to UI thread?